# `load_dependency': undefined method `activate' for Gem:Module (NoMethodError)

Tags: merb, merb-auth

b-core-1.0.13/lib/merb-core/core_ext/kernel.rb:142:in `load_dependency': undefined method`activate' for Gem:Module (NoMethodError)
    from /home/subrahmanyam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374@mostfit/gems/merb-core-1.0.13/lib/merb-core/bootloader.rb:405:in `load_dependencies'
    from /home/subrahmanyam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374@mostfit/gems/merb-core-1.0.13/lib/merb-core/bootloader.rb:405:in`each'
    from /home/subrahmanyam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374@mostfit/gems/merb-core-1.0.13/lib/merb-core/bootloader.rb:405:in `load_dependencies'
    from /home/subrahmanyam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374@mostfit/gems/merb-core-1.0.13/lib/merb-core/bootloader.rb:393:in`run'

Merb was working good before I update rubygems . Now it is showing the above error .
please help me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think this problem is due to the usage of older version of merb application. Since the merb application is no longer supported, you can try updating the gem list to older version.

You can try this command : `sudo gem update --system <version number>`

Try a version number (say 1.6.2) in the `<version number>`.

Hope this helps.